# atlassian_python_api checking if blogpost exist

Tags: python-3.8, confluence, atlassian-python-api

I'm using atlassian-pytho-api version 3.4.1.
I need to create a blogpost which I successfully made this way

```
confluence.create_page(space, title, content, type="blogpost")
```

Now, I want to update this blogpost under certain conditions, for that i need to check if the post exists or not. I tried using

```
confluence.page_exists(space, title)
```

But it just searches in PAGES not in the blogpost and hence couldn't find the post and I can't update. Is there any way to restrict page_exists to search in blogpost instead of pages ?

Answer (score 0):

i used CQL to search through whole space.

```
space={SPACE_NAME} and type="blogpost and title~{PAGE_TITLE}"
```